# Jquery Datatables filter doesn't work on "ON" & "OFF" strings

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables 1.10.2, filtering is working on all columns including the status column but it doesn't filter when i try to filter records on the string "ON" or "OFF". If i change the same string to say "ONN", then it works. here is table initialization.

```
var _oTable = $('#' + tablename).DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "class": 'details-control',
            "targets": [0],
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {orderable: false, targets: [0, 5] }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, "All"]]
    });
```

Any idea, if someone else also experienced the same issue.

Comment: Any chance we can check your issue online?

Comment: well it is not available on public domain, but if you ask i can provide you with further details.